# Create Ansible task for yum command

Tags: ansible, copr

I am
 trying to convert this yum command to Ansible task:

```
yum -y install yum-plugin-copr
yum -y copr enable @spacewalkproject/nightly-client
```

created task like this, but giving error.

```
  - name:  Install repository yum-plugin-copr
    yum:
      name: "{{ packages }}"
    vars:
      packages:
      - yum-plugin-copr

  - name: Install repository Spacewalk-Client 
    yum:
      name: copr
      enablerepo: "@spacewalkproject/nightly-client"
      state: present
```

Error:

```
Error setting/accessing repos: Error getting repository data for @spacewalkproject/nightly-client, repository not found
```

What is the right way to convert this command to Ansible task?

Thanks
SR

Comment: The error doesn't sound like an Ansible error but like a yum error. Are you sure your command works on the target host?

Comment: my suggestion just for debugging would be to run the same command via `command` module in before using the `yum: enable` module

Comment: @peedee yes, I was able to run the command on that host.

Comment: @error404 now I am running command as shell command it works.

Comment: @sfgroups, have you tried using the [`yum_repository`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/yum_repository_module.html) module to add the repository, and then run the install task?

Answer (score 1):

The `yum` module is meant to install, remove, update and list Yum packages. It doesn't support sub-commands from plugins like [YUM Copr Plugin](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/yum-copr.8.html). Therefore, you can't expect to call `yum copr` sub-command by using this module.

There is [an opened issue to add support to Copr in `dnf` module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/26673), you should take a look and subscribe to the discussion.

Meanwhile, you could try to add the repository with `yum_repository` module, or simply call `yum copr` with the `shell` module.